# how to massupdate in mysql based on variable function?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a game and stuck at this and can't figure it out. I am storing all player information in a MYSQL database.

PLAYER|LOCATION|RESOURCEA|RESOURCEB|B1Buildings|B2Buildings

How can I update/increment RESOURCEA as a function of # in B1Buildings in a loop for all players as a SQL function given that different players may have different number of B1Buildings?

ie. B1Buildings = 2, B1Rate=2x per ServerLoop, ResourceA =ResourceA+b1Rate*b1building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really need a loop. Your requirement is not stated very clearly. At least, I'm not able to decipher exactly what it is you want to accomplish. (Where is `B1Rate` coming from?)

I'm going to assume that `PLAYER` is a unique identifier for a row in your table.

In that case, a simple UPDATE statement would suffice if you can supply a value for B1Rate in the statement:

```
UPDATE mytable t SET t.RESOURCEA = t.RESOURCEA + 2 *t.B1Buildings
```